# How To Access Values In Associative Array Using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, amazon-simpledb

I have an array which is the result of a select query using Amazon SimpleDb.

Here is sample data when I print_r($result);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => 5140ede647e74
                       [Attributes] => Array (
                            [0] => Array ( [Name] => test_id [Value] => 5140ede647e74 )
                            [1] => Array ( [Name] => test_name [Value] => test1 )
                            [2] => Array ( [Name] => last_update [Value] => 1363209702 )
                            [3] => Array ( [Name] => created [Value] => 1363209702 ) ) ) )
```

If I want to extract the test_id and the test_name, how can I do it?  I am currently doing the following

```
<?php foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo $item['Attributes'][0]['Value']; 
    echo $item['Attributes'][1]['Value'];
} ?>
```

But I want to do it by referencing "test_id" and "test_name" because when I delete the domain where the data resides and re-enter the data, the order of each attribute can change so I can't trust that $item['Attributes'][0]['Value'] will always be the test_id

Thanks!

Comment: Please repost the output of `print_r()`, but keep the formatting so it is properly indented across multiple lines.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks for formatting the array.   I learned a trick for next time.  If you print_r() an array, when you look at it in a browser it is not formatted well.  But at least in Firefox, when I view source, the array is nicely formatted.

Comment: Wrap it in `<pre>...</pre>` when printing in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
  foreach ($item['Attributes'] as $keyvalue) {
    if ($keyvalue['Name'] == 'test_id' || $keyvalue['Name'] == 'test_name') {
      echo $keyvalue['Value'];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to recast the Array.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($result as $key=>$row)
{        
    foreach ($row['Attributes'] AS $row2)
    {
         $newArray[$key][$row2['Name']] = $row2['Value'];
    }       
}
```

EDIT:  It depends on what you need to do - this is my preferred method if I plan on doing a lot of work with a resultset - I only need to iterate through the set once and then it's in a format where the data can be accessed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The following will run trough the last part of your array by reference. Therefore edits that you make are reflected in the `$result` array.

```
foreach ($result[0]['Attributes'] as &$item) {
    if ($item['Name'] == 'test_id') // do something
}
```